# Interchangeable arms in Wheatstone Bridge

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current

[image]

I came across this fact recently but cannot seem to make much clarity out of it.

With reference to the picture above the condition for balancing the Wheatstone bridge is that B and D should be at the same potential.
However this is not possible if we connect a battery in between B and D.

Could someone provide clarity,
a proof and some applications of this fact...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Proxy explains, do not interpret their statement to mean that you can simply swap the position of the battery & meter **with no other** changes.  When you make this swap, the other 2 nodes become the equipotential points when the circuit is balanced.

In my right-hand figure below I have swapped the battery and the meter.  In the second drawing I merely rotated the resistors ccw 90°.  The bridge will work this way too (because it is symmetrical).

In the **left** figure, we adjust $R_3$ until there is no current measured by G (indicating no potential difference between A & B). At this point, $\color{blue}{R_X} = R_2\times\frac{R_3}{R_1}$.

In the **right** figure, we adjust $R_2$ until there is no current measured by G. At this point, $\color{blue}{R_X} = R_3\times\frac{R_2}{R_1}$.

See the [Wheatstone wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge) for details and derivation.

[image]

Comment: Oh alright I get it now. I was making the swap and the potentials at different points did not match.... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Interchanging the places of cell and galvanomenter is also equivalent to switching the places of resistors $Q$ and $R$ .Think it this way:

Initially the galvanometer is between points $B $ and $D$. And the cell is between A and C. Now if you interchange the resistors $ Q$ and $R$, and rename the nodes $ A, B, C, D $ accordingly you find that you interchange the places of galvanomenter and cell. That is $ A \rightarrow B$ , $B \rightarrow A$ ,$ D  \rightarrow C$ and $C  \rightarrow D$. Following these changes the cell is now between $B$ and $ D$, and galvanomenter in between $ A$ and $C$ as required.

I also realized one thing which is a cause of confusion, the points $B$ and $D$ do not require to be at same potential, since we interchange galvanomenter with the cell, we need $A$ and $C$ to be at same potential.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This makes it more clear